# Frequency Distribution with weighted average

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have data in the following format :

```
TYPE AMOUNT
Book   £2
Pen    £1
Book   £3
```

I'm trying to output this as a weighted average :

```
TYPE Weighted Average
Book 0.833333333
Pen  0.166666667
```

So far I have :

```
Select TYPE, AMOUNT/SUM(AMOUNT) 
FROM MyTable
Group by TYPE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you the result you want:

```
select type
    , cast(sum(amount) as decimal(10,5))/(select sum(amount) from t)
from t
group by type
```

See [Sql Fiddle for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38eed/17)

Comment: +1. Not that it would matter much but OP might remove the cast if `amount` is already defined as decimal.

Comment: @Lieven that's correct, I only added it based on the data that was provided was all `int`s so I added the `cast()`

Answer (score 0):

This Will Work

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (TYPE  VARCHAR(10),AMOUNT FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @Table1 SELECT  'Book',2 UNION ALL SELECT 'Pen',1 UNION ALL  SELECT 'Book',3

DECLARE @Total FLOAT
SELECT @Total=SUM(AMOUNT) FROM @Table1

SELECT TYPE,SUM(AMOUNT/@Total) FROM @Table1 GROUP BY TYPE
```